# Test switch case in Jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, tdd, karma-jasmine

I'm learning to write test case in jasmine i have a function which contains the switch statement as follows

```
public onMReceived(event) {
    switch (event && event['event']) {
      case 'onOplected':
        this.Next();
        break;

      case 'temp':
        break;
    }
  }
```

I had written the proper test case ,when the case is onOplected but to cover the other case when case is 'temp'

```
 it('should call temp on onOplected value in switch', () => {
    //const toggleSpy = spyOn<any>(component, 'Next');
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.onMessageReceived({ event: 'temp', data: {} });
    // expect(toggleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(undefined);
  });
```

how should I write expect for it ,please if anyone can help on this please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can test that next was not called or something like this.

```
 it('should do nothing if the event is temp and not call next', () => {
    const toggleSpy = spyOn<any>(component, 'Next');
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.onMessageReceived({ event: 'temp', data: {} });
    // also change your toHaveBeenCalledWith(undefined) to .toHaveBeenCalled() in your previous test
    expect(toggleSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled(); // put .not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```